# Generating random date in specfic range in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I have recently starting learning Grails and Groovy and quite stuck generating a date in a certain range.

I can generate a date based on a year difference. But how do I add a month and date?

This is what I got, using DatesUtils

```
DateUtils.addYears(new Date() , -(18 + new Random().nextInt(20)))
```

This works to generate a date based on year. But I will be having the same month all the time. How to add a month into this so I can randomize the month as well

Comment: adding an int to a date in groovy adds the number of days to the date.  what range or quality of "random" are we talking here?

Comment: What I have done works fine, what is an issue though is the fact that the date generate always has the same month and day. That is not very realistic if I am generating users with the same month and day. So the quality is an issue, yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way of doing it:

```
Date randomDate(Range<Date> range) {
    range.from + new Random().nextInt(range.to - range.from + 1)
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
def start = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2015-01-01')
def end   = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2015-01-10')
println randomDate(start..end)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a random date between 18 and 38 years ago.  If this is true, you could do something like this:

```
Date curdate = new Date()
// compute the beginning and end of the range that you want to find a date between.
// note, I used a simple 365 day year, but you could use Calendar or even DateUtils
// to compute the actual dates of 18 and 38 years ago 
Date ago18yrs = curdate - (18*365)
Date ago38yrs = curdate - (38*365) 
// compute the number of days in the range
int daysbetween = ago18yrs.minus( ago38yrs )
// add a random number of days in the range to the beginning of the range
Date randomdate = ago38yrs + new Random().nextInt(daysbetween)
```

At that point, randomdate should be a random Date between 18 and 38 years ago.